# systemd-ask-password Only Prompt on Current Console

Tags: centos, systemd

*CentOS 7*

I am using `systemd-ask-password` as part of the script that starts my `systemd` service. The problem is that `systemd-ask-password` prompts for the input on ***EVERY*** open terminal. I need to prompt on ***ONLY*** the terminal for the user starting the service.

One thing that I tried was to stop `systemd-ask-password-wall.service` and start `systemd-ask-password-console.service`. This worked, but it seems to be the wrong thing to do based on the description of `systemd-ask-password-console.service`:

> A boot-time password agent querying the user directly on the console

How can I make `systemd-ask-password` prompt only on the terminal of the user starting the service? Or do I need to do something else entirely? Is it appropriate to use `systemd-ask-password-console.service` in place of `systemd-ask-password-wall.service`?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent wall messages from messing up all of your open terminals:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-ask-password-wall.service
sudo systemctl stop systemd-ask-password-wall.path
```

To make this change persistent over boot:

```
sudo systemctl mask systemd-ask-password-wall.service
sudo systemctl mask systemd-ask-password-wall.path
```